# Avoid Android service getting killed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application that implements a remote background service. This service is implemented to download files in threads (I would say this service works as a download manager).

When I want to download a file, I send the url to the service, and the service starts a thread (I was using AsyncTask but it only worked in Android 4.1) where it actually downloads the file. But sooner or later the download stops, and I was able to know that because the notification I show doesn't get updated anymore. When I click the notification to cancel the download, a pending intent is sent to the service to tell it to cancel the download, but not download is cancelled as the service is re-created (onCreate gets called).

*Edit:* Forgot to say that I return START_STICKY in onStartCommand()

What solutions do I have? Any way to avoid the service getting killed?

I was looking also into startForeground(), and that would be ok if the service target is to download only one file but I want support to download multiple file simultaneously.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the only way to prevent your service from being killed is to use `startForeground()`. Even this won't guarantee that Android won't kill your service, but there isn't anything better. We've had good success using foreground services.

Comment: Thanks. I finally limited my service to only one download at once and used startForeground(). Working like a charm!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do multiple parallel downloads using foreground service? You can download each file in a separate thread. There's no reason why this can't work.

Comment: I can do it, of course, but I need a way to call startForeground() without passing a notification.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid this in system i have seen is to make Service as a System Service but for that you need to have a privilege of AOSP and extend the class SystemService.

Such SystemService need to be compiled and created as part of the services.jar which is a composition of all the System Services of android. Unfortunately this adds to the risk of System Services stability considering that external service may bring up issues to system.

Of course this is not something which is easily possible for application developers but rather this approach is more for the OEMs / SoC vendors who work on full AOSP.